# SQL Server 2014 dbCreator role not created

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2014-express

Installed SQL server 2014 using

```
en_sql_server_2014_management_studio_with_service_pack_2_x64_9009295.exe
```

First, I am not getting the screen where you can create default instance and create `sa` login. So once it got installed, I go to SQL Server Express and logged in with Windows Authentication, but I see a Red downward arrow for sa login under Security\Logins. This makes me unable to create database giving error

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database master. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:262)

Please advise!

Comment: You obviously installed ***ONLY*** the management studio - that's ***ONLY*** the GUI application to manage SQL Server - but this is ***NOT*** the core, SQL Server **database engine** that actually manages your data! Read [this blog post by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx) who explains in great details and with lots of examples on what to download for **SQL Server Express**

Answer (score 0):

change the type of authentification from windows authentification to sql server authentification and give the dbowner to sa in master database